# What is the advantage of using the below input format in Google Translate API

Tags: json, api-design, google-translate

The Google Translate API right now takes multiple inputs to be translated as below:

```
--data "{'q': 'Hello world','q': 'My name is Jeff','target': 'de'}"
```

Instead of using multiple entries like above for 'q' they could have use array like below:

```
 --data "{'q':['Hello world','My name is Jeff'],'target': 'de'}"
```

What is the advantage of the 1st format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested both versions and I got the same result, with the messages translated in German.

Try this code:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \   
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \ 
    --data "{'q':['Hello world','My name is Jeff'],'target': 'de'}" \
"https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
```

You will get this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "Mein Name ist Jeff",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You may need authentication credentials for this to work, follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) to add those credentials and then test the code above.